# How do you open a program by using ActionListener in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, actionlistener

I am busy creating a GUI in Java with buttons such that if I press a button it must open another program like Excel or Word and also a folder. Is there anyway that this is possible?

Answer (score 6):

You would do something like this...

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
       Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\a.doc"));
}
```

If they have word then this file will open in word.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Replace the string notepad with your program name with it's path.
To open a folder use `"explorer c:\\z"` in the place of notepad string to open folder `z` for Windows OS. Use `"nautilus /directory"` to open directory for Linux OS.

```
try{
        java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Please read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) in any example using `exec`.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.  `Desktop.open(File)` is a better path for this functionality, but using a `Process` will work if it is not inherently ..fragile (as in the above example).